# How to use a shell variable in tmux command?

Tags: python, bash, shell, tmux

I'm writing a shell script that determines some variables, e.g. an open port. Then it opens some tmux windows, in which python programs are executed. These python programs should take the port as a command line argument, as such:

```
function find_open_port(){
    # Ports between 49152 - 65535 are usually unused.
    port=$(shuf -i '49152-65535' -n '1')

    # Then check if port is open
    if lsof -Pi :$port -sTCP:LISTEN -t >/dev/null ; then
        find_open_port
    else
        # There is no service currently running on this port
        return $port
    fi
}

find_open_port
echo "Using port: $port"

tmux new-session -d -s '1' 'python server.py -p $port'
sleep 2
tmux split-window -v -t '1' 'python client.py -p $port'
sleep 1
tmux split-window -h -t '1' 'python client.py -p $port'
```

If I determine the port as an integer instead of the variable, it works (e.g. 1025), but I want to run parallel instances of this, therefore I need to randomly choose several different ports. The tmux command doesn't seem to "take" the port variable.

How do I get tmux to take the value of the variable?

Comment: You don't actually have to quote the entire command. `tmux new-session -d -s 1 python server.py -p "$port"` will work. (Even `$port` could be left unquoted, since you *expect* the value to be a simple integer, but it's good practice to quote parameter expansions.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single quote doesn't allow variable expansion, use double quote:

```
tmux split-window -v -t '1' "python client.py -p $port"
```

Comment: Thank you, it's always the most trivial problems that take the longest to figure out... -.-